# Change content of control in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have created a new control from an inheritance:

```
L.Control.extend({
            options: {
                position: position,

                descriptionHeader: 'This is a description',
                descriptionText: 'Label',

                counterHeader: 'This is a description',
                counterText: 'Label',

                className: 'leaflet-control-custom',
                labelClassName: 'button-label'
            },
            setDescriptionHeader(text: string){
                console.log("here");
                this.options.descriptionHeader = text;
            },
            setDescriptionText(text: string){
                this.options.descriptiontext = text;
            },
            setDescriptionCounterHeader(text: string){
                this.options.counterHeader = text;
            },
            setDescriptionCounterText(text: string){
                this.options.counterText = text;
            },
            onAdd: function (map) {
                let mainContainer: any = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'description-control');
                let container: any = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'description-options');
                let counterContainer: any = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'description-options-2');


                let header: HTMLElement = document.createElement("h2");
                header.className = 'description-title';
                header.innerText = this.options.descriptionHeader;
                container.appendChild(header);

                let text: HTMLElement = document.createElement("span");
                text.className = 'description-text';
                text.innerText = this.options.descriptionText;
                container.appendChild(text);


                let counter: HTMLElement = document.createElement("h2");
                counter.className = this.options.labelClassName;
                counter.innerText = this.options.counterHeader;
                counterContainer.appendChild(counter);

                let counterText: HTMLElement = document.createElement("span");
                counterText.className = this.options.labelClassName;
                counterText.innerText = this.options.counterText;
                counterContainer.appendChild(counterText);


                mainContainer.appendChild(counterContainer);
                mainContainer.appendChild(container);

                return mainContainer;
            }
        });
```

I want this control content to be updated automatically, when an external variable change or when an action is triggered:

I want to be able to pass some variables to the control to update its text.
I've tried several solution like setting setters for variables, but its not working.

The control looks like the following:

[image]

How do I update the content of my control?